# How to find the width of a knitR pdf so I can center text

Tags: r, pdf, text, r-markdown, knitr

I am creating a PDF using KnitR, whoever I would like to figure out what the exact width of the document is, or how I can set it. Once I have the correct width I can center my text using this. Right now I am using `getOption("width")` but this seems unaccurate

```
centerText <- function() {
  width <- getOption("width")
  out <- "your text"
  ws <- rep(" ", floor((width - nchar(out))/2))
  cat(ws, out, sep = "")
}
centerText()
```

I haven't been able to find better code to center text inside a code chunk, but if anyone knows a better way that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's your output format? pdf or html? and You want to center text of the source code itself?

Comment: The output format is PDF. It's the texts produced by the source code (out <- "your text") that should get centered. I think, that right now using `ggetOption("width")`, it centers it based on the width of Rstudio, not the output file. But I might be wrong.

Comment: One of the solutions that work "better", was for me to figure out how many letters I could print in a PDF (97, if I stopped at the start of the margin) and used that number instead of width. Not elegant though, so still hoping for a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating pdfs, I think a easier solution would be using latex.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

### centering a text

```{r, results='asis'}
centerText <- function(text) {
  out <- paste0("\\centerline{", text, "}")
  cat(out)
}
centerText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
```

### centering a paragraph

```{r, results='asis'}
centerParagraph <- function(text) {
  out <- paste0("\\begin{quotation}\n\\noindent\n", text, "\\end{quotation}\n")
  cat(out)
}

centerParagraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, urna
consequat felis vehicula class ultricies mollis dictumst, aenean non a in donec
nulla. Phasellus ante pellentesque erat cum risus consequat imperdiet aliquam,
integer placerat et turpis mi eros nec lobortis taciti, vehicula nisl litora tellus
ligula porttitor metus. ")
```
````

---

[image: Centering text]

---